# Where are the logs for ufw located on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, ufw

I have an Ubuntu server where I am blocking some IPs with `ufw`. I enabled logging, but I don't know where to find the logs. Where might the logs be or why might `ufw` not be logging?

Comment: Google is your friend http://askubuntu.com/questions/113439/ufw-is-not-logging-how-do-i-troubleshoot

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Perform `sudo ufw status verbose` to see if you're even logging in the first place. If you're not, perform `sudo ufw logging on` if it isn't. If it is logging, check `/var/log/` for files starting with `ufw`. For example, `sudo ls /var/log/ufw*`

If you are logging, but there are no `/var/log/ufw*` files, check to see if `rsyslog` is running: `sudo service rsyslog status`. If rsyslog is running, ufw is logging, and there are still no logs files, search through common log files for any mention of `UFW`. For example: `grep -i ufw /var/log/syslog` and `grep -i ufw /var/log/messages` as well as `grep -i ufw /var/log/kern.log`.

If you find a ton of `ufw` messages in the syslog, messages, and kern.log file, then rsyslog might need to be told to log all UFW messages to a separate file. Add a line to the top of `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` that says the following two lines:

```
:msg, contains, “UFW” -/var/log/ufw.log
& ~
```

And you should then have a ufw.log file that contains all `ufw` messages!

### NOTE:

Check the `50-default.conf` file for pre-existing configurations.

Make sure to backup the file before saving edits!

### UPDATE for Ubuntu Server 20.04 and later

As of Ubuntu 20.04 and later, the `~` is deprecated and should not be used, as reported in the ubuntu 20.04 system log:

```
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, on or before line 6: invalid character '�' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
Jan 26 12:10:27 ubuntu rsyslogd: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]
```

Rather, you should replace it with the word `stop`. So if you still want to log all ufw messages in rsyslog to a seperate ufw.log file then you should add the following to your `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file:

```
:msg, contains, “UFW” -/var/log/ufw.log
& stop
```

instead of

```
:msg, contains, “UFW” -/var/log/ufw.log
& ~
```

Comment: It looks like the `ufw status` (and `ufw status verbose`) commands return if the _firewall its self_ is running, not logging. If the command comes back as inactive, then I believe that means that ufw is totally disabled (which it is on my system). I'm curious now what firewall _is_ running!

Edit: According to the [Ubuntu Server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html), there is no firewall enabled by default - iptables is essentially the firewall. You can follow the linked guide to get ufw running.

Comment: Maybe update your answer that these days there is /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf with the correct config.

Comment: The output of `sudo ufw status verbose` is "Logging: on (low)". I have no logs. How can I set it to as high as possible?

Answer (score 12):

You can also find UFW's logs in the kernel buffer.

```
sudo dmesg | grep '\[UFW'
```

Comment: this is a great answer!