# How do I test my firewall rules?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, testing, nmap, ufw

I've setup some rules in `ufw` on a remote server and I've turned the firewall on. Now I want to ensure my rules actually block traffic. However, when running `nmap -PN -p <my_port> <ip>` from my local workstation it appears the port I'm blocking is still open. At least `nmap` is reporting 'open' (which doesn't seem right). On the server if I run `ufw status verbose` it reports:

```
...
Status: Active
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
To          Action   From
--          ------   ----
22          ALLOW IN Anywhere
<my_port>   DENY IN  Anywhere
```

Shouldn't this `nmap` be reporting  as closed? How do I correctly test these rules?

Answer (score 1):

The way I test if a rule works: `telnet host port`

If it times out (or responds however the firewall should reject), then no connection will be established, which means the firewall is blocking the traffic as desired. If the rule does not work, you'll see some kind of response. Might not work in 100% of situations, but for the usual stuff someone does at home it's enough.

Comment: And there should be a rejection in the ufw logging. https://serverfault.com/questions/516838/where-are-the-logs-for-ufw-located-on-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 0):

from your output: it says that by default `ufw` deny all incoming traffic and you just opened port 22 to be allowed in, so then for your test, you *SHOULD* be able to ssh in via port 22 as port is open, and whenever you try to reach out to any other ports they'll be closed/deny.