# UFW Doesn't Log Until Reboot

Tags: linux, logging, ufw

I am running UFW on a Pi and I have a cron job which backs up the log file and then removes it.

However, UFW doesn't recreate the log until after a reboot.

After removing the file and confirming that the log wasn't recreated I checked the status of UFW which indicated it was active and logging.

How can I get UFW to recreate the ufw.log file (and write to it) after I delete it?

Comment: Use copy & truncate instead of backup & remove.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem. this link was very helpful for me
[Where are the logs for ufw located on Ubuntu Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/516838/where-are-the-logs-for-ufw-located-on-ubuntu-server)
I hope that it helps you also

Regard

Cees